# not working mouseover DOM img on js

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I'm create 3 picts in js. **What I want**: When I over mouse on picture, description shows up.

But working only first img. How to correct check on what the picture mouseover? I'll try documentID and Name, but it isn't work.
My code:

```
    // Воин
var imgW = document.createElement ('img');
    imgW.src = 'img/warrior.png';
    imgW.id = 'imgWarrior';
    imgW.name = 'imgWarrior';
    //img.setAttribute('onClick', 'imgClick();');
    imgW.setAttribute('onMouseOver', 'imgOver();');
    imgW.setAttribute('onMouseOut', 'imgOut();');
    document.getElementById('q').appendChild(imgW);
    // Охотник
var imgH = document.createElement ('img');
    imgH.src = 'img/hunter.png';
    imgH.id = 'imgHunter';
    imgH.name = 'imgHunter';
    //img.setAttribute('onClick', 'imgClick();');
    imgH.setAttribute('onMouseOver', 'imgOver();');
    imgH.setAttribute('onMouseOut', 'imgOut();');
    document.getElementById('q').appendChild(imgH);
    // Маг
var imgM = document.createElement ('img');
    imgM.src = 'img/mage.png';
    imgM.id = 'imgMage';
    imgM.name = 'imgMage';
    //img.setAttribute('onClick', 'imgClick();');
    imgM.setAttribute('onMouseOver', 'imgOver();');
    imgM.setAttribute('onMouseOut', 'imgOut();');
    document.getElementById('q').appendChild(imgM);

function imgOver () {
    if (imgW) {
        document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Блядский Воин</strong>.</p>';
    }else if (imgH){
        document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Охотник за шелупонью</strong>.</p>';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '<p><strong>Маг подщельник</strong>.</p>';
    };
}
    function imgOut () {
    document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issues were just some small syntax errors. Most obvious ones being using setAttribute to define the click handlers, use either .onclick on the element, or the addEventListener() method, also onmouseover and onmouseout are lower case.

Here is an update to the code:

```
// Mage
var imgM = document.createElement ('img');
imgM.src = 'http://3runbrothers.ru/im/mage.png';
imgM.id = 'imgMage';
imgM.name = 'imgMage';
imgM.onclick = function(){imgClick()};
imgM.onmouseover = function(){imgOver()};
imgM.onmouseout = function(){imgOut()};
```

And the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/sc8zzkvz/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I know that they can be declared like imgM.onclick

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 images in your html and span elements for the description, you can add hidden and visible classes, and simply toggle them on and off when hovering over the image. For example:

```
<div>
  <img class="image" src="http://charlottemcmanus.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/butterclock-2.jpg" />
  <span class="hidden">image 1 description</span>
</div>

<div>
  <img class="image" src="http://charlottemcmanus.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/butterclock-2.jpg" />
  <span class="hidden">image 2 description</span>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, have a look at the addClass, removeClass, toggleClass methods for help. They are useful for manipulating styles in your elements. I found the description element with the .next() method, however you could think of a better approach.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( ".image" ).hover(
    function() {
      $(this).next('span').toggleClass('visible');
    }, function() {
      $(this).next('span').toggleClass('visible');
    }
  );
});
```

Also add in the CSS styles you will be adding to show and hide your description.

```
.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Here is an example:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/205bwoL6/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, very useful. But I want do that with JavaScript only.

I create a mini-game. I have 3 always empty DIV. In DIV I create some stuff. First - 3 img. When I click on img all objects in that DIV erase and shows up another stuff like quest with choice. 3 buttons with options for further action.

Maybe you you know where I read how to do these things? tutorial?

Comment: Did you want to give an example of your code on jsFiddle or CodePen and I can Fork it to try to fix the issue.